# spring clould oauth2 redirect to "/" after login with spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm a new comer for the spring oauth2. With the document check, I do a simple function for the oauth2 in a spring cloud alibaba nacos environment.

In the design, I want to add redirect for oauth request from gateway to auth micro service. Then auth micro service authorize with form login, and authorize the scope, then redirect to the redirect url set in oauth url.

When raising request to auth micro service directly, it works well. But if raising request to gateway, after log in, it will redirect to "/" direction and raise 404 error.

With investigation for **SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler**, I found the session contained in request in null. Further more, I check the **HttpSessionRequestCache**, it also gets null session when saving the request. Since the request is not saved, it can't redirect to origin url after login and redirect to default url "/".

But I don't know why the request related session is empty. I also try to do a demo project like following:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "hello",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public RedirectView hello(HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println("Hello:"+request.getSession().getId());
        return new RedirectView("thanks");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "thanks",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> thanks(HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println("Thanks:"+request.getSession().getId());
        return new ResponseEntity("aaa",HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The printed session id are different when using gateway. But without gateway, they are same. The following is my gateway settings:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: flower-gateway
  cloud:
    nacos:
      discovery:
        server-addr: 127.0.0.1:8848
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: order-routes
          uri: lb://flower-order
          predicates:
            - Path=/order/**
        - id: core-routes
          uri: lb://flower-core
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
        - id: auth-routes
          uri: lb://flower-auth
          predicates:
            - Path=/oauth/**
```

So I guess that this is caused by spring cloud gateway. But I don't know how to fix it. Please give me some information. Thanks.

---

New updates:

As I change the auth gateway to

```
- id: auth-routes
          uri: https://127.0.0.1:8082
          predicates:
            - Path=/oauth/**
```

it passes normal behavior. So does it means that it is caused by load balance. But as I just have one running entity, not quite sure. Does this mean it should use the distribute session management such as spring session? As in actual production environment, the auth service won't only have one entity.

Comment: I am new to spring cloud gateway as well, **uri: lb://flower-order** , is 'lb' a place holder for load balancer dns or its a declarative way  + if its declarative how cloud gateway will know which load balancer

Comment: Hi Ajeet, this uses spring cloud alibaba nacos client. So I do a client registory to nacos, it can use the lb for load balance

Comment: Hey @Ajeet, I tried to change lb to actual http url, it works. It seems that this is caused by load balance as you mentioned. But not quite sure how to fix it with having load balance settings.